# .replace() not working in embedded javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, replace, ejs

When I try to run the following code, it doesn't replace the &lt, &gt, &#34 to its equivalent caharacters

```
<% if(typeof myTable !== 'undefined'){ %>
        <% myTable = myTable.replace('&lt','<').replace('&gt', '>').replace('&#34', '"') %>
        <script>
            localStorage['text'] += "<%= myTable %>";
        </script>
        <% myTable = undefined; %>
<% } %>
```

When I check the value of myTable, substituted in the plceholder tag of ejs, it still has these characters in their raw form.

```
myTable = "&lt;table class=&#34;table table-bordered table-hover&#34;&gt;&lt;thead&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;th class=&#34;col&#34;&gt;&lt;p contenteditable=&#34;true&#34;&gt;Head&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/th&gt;&lt;th class=&#34;col&#34;&gt;&lt;p contenteditable=&#34;true&#34;&gt;Head&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/th&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/thead&gt;&lt;tbody&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;p contenteditable=&#34;true&#34;&gt;Null&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;p contenteditable=&#34;true&#34;&gt;Null&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;p contenteditable=&#34;true&#34;&gt;Null&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;p contenteditable=&#34;true&#34;&gt;Null&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/tbody&gt;&lt;/table&gt;"
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to store the value of the replaced string

```
<% myTable = myTable.replace('&lt','<').replace('&gt', '>').replace('&#34', '"') %>
```

Otherwise it's just lost.

From the [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

> The replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and **returns a new string** where the specified values are replaced.

If this doesn't work, try an unescaped version of the bee sting: `"<%- myTable %>";` (instead of `"<%= myTable %>";`).

Comment: Right. I mis-typed here. In my actual code, I have assigned it to myTable.

Comment: Try an unescaped version of the bee sting: `"<%- myTable %>";` (instead of `"<%= myTable %>";`) It's not that clear what you do with this string, though.

Comment: Actually, I want to append to an editable div, a table with given rows and columns on the click of a button. So, the server side gives me a table in string format and I just want to append it to my local storage. But it still has those ascii characters.

Comment: <%-   %>  works. I get my table in the content. Thank you so much. Add that line in your actual answer so that I can mark it as the answer...

Answer (score 1):

You should notice **g** flag and use **myTable = myTable.replace** instead of **myTable.replace**

Because replace method will not change the source string, See:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Try code below:

```js
var myTable = "&lt;table class=&#34;table table-bordered table-hover&#34;&gt;&lt;thead&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;th class=&#34;col&#34;&gt;&lt;p contenteditable=&#34;true&#34;&gt;Head&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/th&gt;&lt;th class=&#34;col&#34;&gt;&lt;p contenteditable=&#34;true&#34;&gt;Head&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/th&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/thead&gt;&lt;tbody&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;p contenteditable=&#34;true&#34;&gt;Null&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;p contenteditable=&#34;true&#34;&gt;Null&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;p contenteditable=&#34;true&#34;&gt;Null&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;p contenteditable=&#34;true&#34;&gt;Null&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/tbody&gt;&lt;/table&gt;"
myTable = myTable.replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>').replace(/&#34;/g, '"');

console.log(myTable);
```

Comment: Right. I mis-typed here. In my actual code, I have assigned it to myTable. Then I ran your code, it still odesn't work. It works in the browser javascript console, but not in the ejs.

Comment: Why don't you do your work in javascript, then output myTable to template?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am also using localStorage to save my data every second, so when I submit the form, it gets reloaded and the Javascript content is lost. Thats why I run it on server side and just pass the result as object. I will consider this way after I complete my project because it might need a bit of research. Thank you anyway. And yes, <%-  %>  using this solved my issue.